texstudio does not detect my bibliographic citations
I have this error in texstudio that does not let me load the quotes even though the .bib file exists:
Process started: bibtex main
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I could not open the apa.bst style file.
---line 9 of the main.aux file
 : \bibstyle{apa
 : }
I am skipping the remainder of this command.
Illegal, another command \bibstyle---line 574 of the file main.aux
 : \bibstyle
 : {apacite}
I am skipping the remainder of this command
I found no style file---while reading the main.aux file.
(There were 3 error messages)

SO. Ubuntu 24.04
Tex-live
Texstudio

welcome! you have errors in your .tex file which are causing errors to be written to the .aux and these are fatal. since you've not shared the code responsible, it is hard to diagnose precisely what's wrong. it looks as if you may have more than one \bibstyle command in your document, which you shouldn't. do you actually have \bibstyle{apa:} somewhere? what does kpsewhich apa.bst return on the command line?

The error messages aren't that hard to parse. First, your document contains two \bibliographystyle directives; that's not legal. Second, the directive \bibliographstyle{apa} can't be executed properly because BibTeX can't find the file apa.bst. ("bst" is short for "bibtex style".) Do get rid of the first \bibliographystyle directive. If you want to keep using the apacite bibliography style, you will also need to load the apacite citation management package. If you choose to proceed along this path, be sure not to load other citation management packages (say, natbib or cite).

Off-topic: TeXstudio is just a front end to a TeX distribution; it does not, by itself, issue error and warning packages. I take it that this TeX distribution is TeXLive. Which version of TeXLive do you employ, and when did you last update it?

there is no apa.bst in texlive. whatever documentation you saw that said to use that bibliography sty;e must also have provided a link to the file.
